# How to increase the Hard disk space in Vmware workstation with MAC Leopard

Tags: mac, vmware-workstation

I am using pre made image of MAC OS Leopard 10.5.7 using an iso called darwin.iso as cd drive which boots the OS.

Now Everything is working fine but the Hard -disk is only 16GB. I have increased the Hard disk of Virtual machine in vmware but MAC OS hard disk still shows 16GB.

is there any way to increase that space.

DO i have to chnage anything in that ISO ore dit the ISO image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to resize the filesystem of the virtual disk inside MacOS. For this, you have different possibilities:

- First, create a second virtual disk and copy the data over to the new disk, maybe with the involvement of Time Machine or Carbon Copy Cloner
- Second, use an external tool like [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php)
- Third, use [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/55274/2007/02/marchgeekfactor.html) undocumented method (and don't forget to backup!)

Comment: so you mean to say that if vmware is showing HD of size 100Gb and mac is only showing 16GB , it means the extra space is there but has not been defined in mac

Comment: Exactly. It's the same with every filesystem: When you create it, it has a defined size, which will not change when you change the size of the underlying partition. 

Oh, and I added the link for the third method.

Comment: thanks buddy , i tried evrything but was not able to increase the size, but i added new virtual hard disk using vmware and it came alright there